# Can I ONLY show the pages that have been promoted/posted as News inside the "PnP - Search Results"

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, pnp-search-webparts

I added the PnP search SPFx web parts as mentioned in this link @ https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/using-the-pnp-modern-search-web-parts/ba-p/2239771

Now inside the "PnP - Search Results" web part, i defined the following to show SharePoint Pages:-

[image]

[image]

The above is working well where it is retrieving all the SharePoint pages as per the "Refinement filters".. but is there a way to do extra filter/refiner to ONLY show the Pages that have been promoted/posted as News, and not to show all the Pages (even the ones that have not been posted as News)?

**Edit:**
I tried to use the PromotedState managed properties as follow:-

[image]
&
[image]

But i will always get zero result...

**EDIT - 2**
I modified the refiner as follow:-

```
PromotedState:2
```

and now the search result is only showing modern pages posted as News. but i define a "PnP - Search Filters" and i chose the "SiteTitle" as the fiilter, but the filter drop-down will only show 2 sites titles (Testing & Hub) as follow:-

[image]

while i have atleast 3 sites where the News pages are coming from (testing,Hub & Technology), as follow:-

[image]

so why the "PnP - Search Filters"  is not showing all the site titles from the "PnP - Search Results" web part? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **PromotedState** managed property to only show the Pages that have been promoted/posted as News.

Different values for this property:

PromotedState=0 => this is a page

PromotedState=1 => this is a news post, not published

PromotedState=2 => this is a news post, published

Comment: i tried this but the web part will always return zero result.. can you check my edit please?

Comment: Both KQL (Keyword Query Language) and FQL (Fast Query Language) expressions work here, I could reproduce your issue when use FQL, as a workaround, use KQL as shown below:  PromotedState:2

Comment: yes your point is correct, the PnP Search Result is now only showing the News pages.. but the  "PnP - Search Filters"  web part is not working correctly.. can you please check  my `edit - 2` section inside my original question ?

Comment: Please check if you specify the "# of values" setting, which means the maximum number of filter values/buckets to return, make sure the value is greater than the number of sites.

Comment: i already define the number of values to be 15 ... not sure why it is not working? is it working as expected at your end?

Comment: Yes, it is working as expected at my end, I set it to 5 since I have 4 sites including news post.